# How to install and run python using Linux terminal on samsung chromebook chromeOS?

Tags: python, linux, google-chrome-os

I am trying to run python on my samsung chromebook. i am using Linux terminal, but when i try to run python i get errors. i am a beginner with no prior knowledge of coding, so it is difficult for me to explain my problem without having a way of providing a visual. im hoping someone has coded with a newer chromebook (at least 2019 or newer) and could possibly help me.

i have looked at several youtube videos and have went to trouble shooting for chromeOS, python and even visual studios and have not found anything that could help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Have a look at this [post](https://codeinstitute.net/global/blog/python-on-a-chromebook/) on to setup linux and python on a chromebook.

Comment: What errors do you get? Please [edit] your question and post them (as text, not a picture). Try running simply `python` or `python3` if you're not already. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask).